# How to return a value from a recursive Python function?

Tags: python, function, recursion, return

I'm writing a password generator, one that takes a string (the URL of a website) and processes it into a secure password that can't be backtracked based on the name of the website.

In part of the code, I created a recursive function that looks like this:

```
def get_number(n = 0, nums = ''):
    for i in range(0, len(url)):
        #both n and nums are changed
    if len(nums) < num_length:
        get_number(n, nums)
    else:
        print(nums)
        return(nums)
```

...

```
print(get_number())
```

I would expect `nums` to output twice, since I print it in the else block and print the return later on. But, if it does go through a recursive loop, `nums` is printed from the else block and the function returns `None`. If `if len(nums) < num_length` is false the first time, then it returns the proper value.

Why would it return `None`, if I verified that the object it is returning is not in fact `None` the line before?

I'm a little new to Python; does it handle recursions differently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're missing a `return` before the nested `get_number`. So, it's executing and returning, but you aren't doing anything with the recursed value.

```
def get_number(n = 0, nums = ''):
    for i in range(0, len(url)):
        #both n and nums are changed
    if len(nums) < num_length:
        return get_number(n, nums)

    print(nums)
    return nums
```

Comment: The point is that you have to return the called function. Some languages allow you to simply return the value on the last called function. I should say some compilers of some languages. C++ for Win32 is one that works this way. The call stack looks to the last recursive call to return the value, but not in python